# Which is the range from which zombies/skeletons would attack me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

From which range will zombies/skeletons would attack me? I noticed that Zombies detect me from a bigger range, but what is this range in blocks and from what range would it be safe to approach a zombie and skeleton group to attract only zombies away from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobs will default their `generic.followRange` base attribute value to 16.0, though certain mobs will use a different value. The following is a list of followRange values for 1.8.

1. Zombies (and therefore Zombie Pigmen as they extend the EntityZombie class): 35.0.
2. Withers: 40.0.
3. Blaze: 48.0.
4. Endermen: 64.0
5. Ghasts: 100.0.
6. As far as the source is concerned, guardians will also set theirs to 16.0, though makes no difference since that's what it would be anyway.

Since skeletons do not change their base value it will remain at 16.0, while zombies will have a base of 35.0, causing them to attack you from further away than skeletons.

Comment: Great info. Could you provide a reference for these numbers?

Comment: @ire_and_curses They come straight from decompiled source (deobfuscated with 1.8 [MCP](http://www.modcoderpack.com/website/releases)). Respective entity classes for all (EntityZombie, EntityWither, EntityBlaze, EntityEnderman, EntityGhast, EntityGuardian) and EntityLiving for parent class for default value of 16.0, method "applyEntityAttributes".

Answer (score 1):

Actually is 16 blocks for both

This is the code where is written (EntityMob Class)
[image: Skeleton/Zombie Code]

Comment: It is not 16 for both. Zombies have their base value set separately in their own class file (35.0 in 1.8 MCP). It appears that the code sample you've provided is also outdated, as the EntityMob class in 1.8 MCP does not include "16" in its file at all. Obtaining targets relies on the `generic.followRange` value, which is set during entity instantiation, rather than a hard-coded value at the time of obtaining a target.

Answer (score 0):

As of now most mobs have a sight radius of 16.  The mobs that don't apply to this rule are enderman that have a sight of 64, and Ghasts that can see up to 100.

There is little on the web, but I found this.
Tests sight through stutter:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/alpha/alpha-survival-single-player/813892-help-confirm-huge-stutter-bug